# Cannot connect GSConnect to KDE Connect in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, kde, connection

I downloaded GSconnect on gnome extension and I downloaded KDE connect on my phone too. but my problem is I can't find my computer on kde connect and my phone on gsconnect aswell. I'm using the same wifi on both devices but no result. Solution?

Comment: Any firewall in the PC?

Comment: Yes there it is

Comment: Does it work off you temporarily disable the firewall?

Comment: Yes thank you so much sir

Comment: Im wondering if connection between my coputer and my phone still work if i turn on the firewall again

Comment: If you think the answer is correct, please accept it by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 0):

**From comments:** OP has firewall enabled and temporarily disabling the firewall makes GSConnect work. Therefore the solution is to:

## Open the ports

> KDE Connect uses dynamic ports in the range 1714-1764 for UDP and TCP.
> So if you are behind a firewall, make sure to open this port range for
> both TCP and UDP. Otherwise, make sure your network is not blocking
> UDP broadcast packets.

source: https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect#Other_Permissions

Hope this helps